# Using a link to submit a form using jQuery Ajax

Tags: laravel-5.3

```
    <a class="btn table-btn delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" href="/fields/{{ hashid_encode($extrafield->id) }}"></a>

<script>
    $('.delete').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();

        var url, data;
        url = $(this).attr('href');
        data = {
          '_method' : 'DELETE',
        }
       request = $.ajax({
            method: "post",
            url: url,
            data: data
        });
     });
 </script>
```

I'm using laravel so my routes look like this :

```
Route::get('/{id}',['as'=>'fields.show','uses'=>'ResourceController@show']);
Route::delete('/{id}', ['as'=>'fields.destroy','uses'=>'ResourceController@destroy']);
```

don't know why it is using Route::get instead of Route::delete even though I'm trying to use the post method requesting ajax. I tried to post it

```
request = $.post({
       url: url, 
       data: data
     });
```

[image]
I'm I doing something wrong here?

Comment: This error is generated when calling the URL directly in the browser?

Comment: @Laerte yes.. I'm sorry. I didn't expect a fast response and was tied up. There error happens when I click the link.

Comment: When you put `href="/fields/{{ hashid_encode($extrafield->id) }}"` in the `<a>` tag, the browser will redirect to the address. So, it will use the GET route. Probably the error is not in your ajax code, but in the `href` attribute.

Comment: Another thing that is probably missing is the `csrf_token` field.

Comment: ok @Laerte .. I will try both to add the token or remove the href and set it as the url in post..and maybe post again

Comment: solved it using form and button and removing the link... like you suggested @Laerte

Comment: Can you post the final code as an answer? So, other people with the same problem can use it as a reference.